Trying to use mat-chips reactive with autocomplete
I'm trying to use matchip with autocomplete enabled, I can't say why it doesn't work
The values ​​passed are correct and I can't use a filter on an observable
Does anyone have a tip on what to do?
Using the example of angular material, the filter and ViewChild were enough, but it didn't work
Using angular v16
https://v16.material.angular.io/components/chips/examples
 <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Selecione os participantes</mat-label>
      <mat-chip-grid #chipGrid>
        <mat-chip-row [removable]="true" *ngFor="let item of allParticipantes" (removed)="remove(item)">
          {{item.funcionario.nome}}
          <button matChipRemove >
            <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-chip-row>
      </mat-chip-grid>
      <input placeholder="Nome dos funcionários" #participantesInput formControlName="participantesCtrl"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipGrid" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)" />
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredParticipantes$| async" [value]="item">{{item.nome}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>


constructor(
    protected _fb: FormBuilder,
    private _reservaSala: ReservaSalaService,
    private _funcionarioService: FuncionarioService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ReservaSala,
    private _storage: StorageService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private participantesService: ParticipantesService,
  ) {

    this.filteredParticipantes$ = this.participantesControle.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((part: string | null) => (part ? this.filter(part) : this.allParticipantes.slice())),);
  }

@ViewChild('participantesInput') participantesInput!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
@ViewChild('auto') matAutocomplete!: MatAutocomplete;

public add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const value = this.form.get('participantes')?.value;
    // const input = event.chipInput;
    if (value) {
      console.log('value no add', value)
      if (this.allParticipantes.includes(value)) {
        const participanteIndividual: Participantes = {
          funcionario: value,
          codParticipantes: 0,
          codReservaSala: 0
        };
        this.allParticipantes.push(participanteIndividual);
      }
    }
    event.chipInput!.clear();
    this.participantesControle.setValue(null);
  }

public selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    event.option.deselect();
    const participanteIndividual: Participantes = {
      funcionario: event.option.value,
      codParticipantes: 0,
      codReservaSala: 0
    };
    this.allParticipantes.push(participanteIndividual);
    this.participantesControle.setValue(null);
  }

  public filter(value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    console.log('filterValue', filterValue)
    return this.allParticipantes.filter((participante) => participante.funcionario.nome.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

